# speeding up complex-number multiplication in C++

Tags: c++

I have some code which multiplies complex numbers, and have noticed that [`mulxc3` (long double version of `muldc3`)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html) is being called frequently: i.e. the complex number multiplications are not being inlined.

I am compiling with `g++` version 7.5, with `-O3` and `--ffast-math`.

It is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438158/why-is-muldc3-called-when-two-stdcomplex-are-multiplied), except the problem persists when I compile with -ffast-math. Since I do not require checking for whether the arguments are `Inf` or `NaN`, I was considering making my own very simple complex class without such checks to allow the multiplication to be inlined, but given my lack of C++ proficiency, and having read [this article](https://medium.com/@smcallis_71148/complex-arithmetic-is-complicated-873ec0c69fc5) makes me think that would be counterproductive.

So, is there a way to change either my code or compilation process so that I can keep using `std::complex`, but inline the multiplication?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a [mre] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm not easily. Every simple example I try has mulxc3 appearing when compiled without optimizations, but the this vanishes when the --ffast-math flag is switched on. It will probably take at least a few hours to pinpoint which part of my code is preventing inlining. I will try to do this and I will edit my question once I have found the section, but in the mean time any answer of the form "[some sort of operation] will prevent inlining for muldc3 occurring in [some context]" would also be very much appreciated

Comment: Maybe its worth trying C types for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540228/c-complex-numbers-in-c

Comment: @Abdurrahim I considered this but would much prefer to use std::complex if possible, because portability is important, and at some point I will have to work on a different OS and use a different compiler or version

Comment: it seems to have been due to an error in my makefile which meant that --ffast-math was not actually being called after all.

Comment: Unless you've conducted profiling and obtained *evidence* that complex multiplication is a performance bottleneck (as distinct from being "done often", which is not the same thing) I suggest not worrying too much about whether the operation is inlined. Modern compilers do a pretty good job - admittedly not perfect - optimising code as needed, and the emitted code is not always intuitive. If you just write code without a stronger case than "I think I can do it faster", it's a good bet that your "hand-rolled to inline" version will be less efficient than what the compiler already does for you.

Comment: in my case, yes, the multiplication was taking over half the CPU time. Ensuring that -ffast-math was actually turned on (so that the multiplication was inlined) meant that my overall runtime decreased by a factor of more than 3. The increase in performance compared to just -O3 was suprising.